# ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, from a Java library

Tags: scala, overloading, scala-java-interop

I was tying to convert [this example](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/#Read) for JsonPath to Scala. It should be easy with java like:

```
List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

Which I converted to this Scala:

```
val authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

Where json is a String.  But I get this compile error.

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method read in object JsonPath of type [T](x$1: String, 
 x$2: String, x$3: <repeated...>[com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter[_]])T and method read in object JsonPath of type 
 [T](x$1: Any, x$2: String, x$3: <repeated...>[com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter[_]])T match argument types 
 (String,String)
```

Which I assume is related to

```
public static <T> T read(Object json, String jsonPath, Filter... filters)
```

and

```
public static <T> T read(String json, String jsonPath, Filter... filters)
```

from com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath (version 0.9.1).

How can I disambiguate this function call?

Comment: Looks like a problem in the *JsonPath* library, because `String` in the first argument will always be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case you could just do

```
JsonPath.read(json.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.store.book[*].author")
```

This will only match one of overloaded methods (the one which takes `Object`). Presumably the method calls `json.toString` which is trivial since we already have a `String`.

Comment: Interesting, I had tried asInstanceOf[String] and asInstanceOf[java.lang.String] without any luck.

Comment: I tried this change. While the compilation error did disappear, running the code resulted in an error of not finding the key within the json:

Property ['s3Bucket'] not found in path $: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['s3Bucket'] not found in path $ at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.token.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:41) ........