# Ambiguous reference to overloaded function in Scala

Tags: scala, aws-lambda

I have written a lambda code that tracks login to AWS console, and send notification to user email about it.

The initial code I have written was in Java, and worked. After converting the code to Scala, I came to the following code:

```
class SNSHandler {

  private val creds: AWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx", "999/xyz12345")
  private val eventType: String = "ConsoleLogin"
  private val topicArn: String = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1111111111:CTInterestingEvents"

  def processLoginRecord(loginRecord: String, lambdaLogger: LambdaLogger) = {
    val userName = JsonPath.read(loginRecord.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.userIdentity.type").asInstanceOf[String] match {
      case "Root" => "Root"
      case _ => JsonPath.read(loginRecord.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.userIdentity.userName")
    }
    val accountId = JsonPath.read(loginRecord.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.userIdentity.accountId")

    new AmazonSNSClient(creds).publish(topicArn, "This is an auto notification message.\nUser " + userName +
      " has logged in to AWS account id " + accountId + ".\n You are receiving this email because someone has subscribed your" +
      " email address to this event.")
  }

  def processCloudTrailBulk(event: String, logger: LambdaLogger) = {
    JsonPath.read(event.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.Records[?(@.eventName == '" + eventType + "' && @.responseElements.ConsoleLogin == 'Success')]").
      asInstanceOf[java.util.List[String]].asScala.map(loginRecord => processLoginRecord(loginRecord, logger))
  }

  def processS3File(bucketName: String, file: String, logger: LambdaLogger) = {
    Source.fromInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new AmazonS3Client(creds).
      getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, file)).getObjectContent),"UTF-8").getLines().
      foreach(line => processCloudTrailBulk(line,logger))
  }

  def processSNSRecord(notification: SNSRecord, logger: LambdaLogger) =  {
    val bucketName: String = JsonPath.read(notification.getSNS.getMessage.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.s3Bucket")
    logger.log("Notifications arrived.\nBucket: " + bucketName)
    JsonPath.read(notification.getSNS.getMessage.asInstanceOf[Object], "$.s3ObjectKey[*]").asInstanceOf[java.util.List[String]].
      asScala.map(file => processS3File(bucketName,file,logger))
  }

  def handleCloudTrailIncoming(event: SNSEvent, context: Context) = {
    event.getRecords.asScala.map(record => processSNSRecord(record,context.getLogger))
  }
}
```

Now, the addition of .asInstanceOf[Object] to the first param of every 'read' call wasn't there initially, however I had the famous compiler error of ambiguous reference to overloaded function, and after taking a look at: [ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, from a Java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331551/ambiguous-reference-to-overloaded-definition-from-a-java-library) I added it, and indeed my code now compiles.

The problem is however that in runtime, the read now fails to detect the fields, and I get the following error:

```
Property ['s3Bucket'] not found in path $: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['s3Bucket'] not found in path $ at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.token.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.‌​java:41) ........
```

Comment: Did you try other JSON libraries for Scala? Taking the Java one is not always the best path.